# Vuetify - Customizations

Tags: vue.js, styles, vuetify.js, customization, styling

Vuetify allows us to change the default themes and presets by using a variables.scss/sass file in our project.
But I am unable to figure out how to change the font-style/font-weight (or any other global properties except the color) for the entire app, dynamically on the fly.
For Example:
We have a vue application running and the global font is currently set to Roboto,
What I want to do is provide a list of available fonts in a v-select and dynamically feed the selected value(suppose Raleway) in the variables.scss file or somehow trigger Vuetify to pick up the updated font-family (even other customizations), and change the default font to Raleway for the entire application.
I don't want to add classes everywhere. It won't be maintainable.

Any ideas on how can this be achieved?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the font app-wide is possible through the [variables file](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/) as you mention, but this is a build-time decision. If you're wanting the user to swap out the font in the running app, there isn't any mechanism for this as far as I know, because the app is already compiled and running.

Comment: Right, I've searched a lot and arrived nowhere.
Do you think the CSS in JS libraries might just do the work? 
Check: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-styled-components
I still need to do a hands-on and see if it is compatible with vuetify and works smoothly.

Comment: Not sure, I would just pick a font and go with it. :)

Comment: RIght, that was the easiest option, but here the use case is a little different, 
I want to provide customization options to users on the fly. 
Nevermind, Thanks!